# Drag and Drop (plus snapping to grid)

Tags: silverlight

Is there a way in Silverlight, to make elements draggable - but also allow these same elements to "snap" to the others?

I've followed a few drag-drop tutorials for this, but none of them seem to allow the snapping :(

Any ideas SO gurus?

**Clarification:** I would like a 32px x 32px "rectangle" to be draggable and snappable to other draggable elements.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This has been sorted, please see my [other Silverlight Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556749/dragging-a-rectangle-which-is-inside-a-grid) for the answer.